# Proving $\phi(x) = \psi(x)$ for all $x \in G$ where $\phi: G \rightarrow G'$ and $\psi: G \rightarrow G'$ and $G$ and $G'$ are isomoprhic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Consider the following task:

> Let $G$ be a cyclic group with generator $a$, and let $G'$ be a group isomorphic to $G$. If $\phi: G \rightarrow G'$ is an isomorphism, show that, for every $x \in G$, $\phi(x)$ is completely determined by the valye $\phi(a)$. That is, if $\phi: G \rightarrow G'$ and $\psi: G \rightarrow G'$ are two isomorphisms such that $\phi(a) = \psi(a)$ then $\phi(x) = \psi(x)$ for all $x \in G$.

We know that $<a> = G$. Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that $\phi(x) \ne \psi(x)$ for *some* $x \in G$. We know that both functions maps $G$ to $G'$. Given that $\phi(a) = \psi(a)$, where $a$ is a generator of $G$, the fact that $\phi(x) \ne \psi(x)$ implies that $G$ and $G'$ are not isomorphic, since $G$ is a cyclic group, which is the desired contradiction.

While my argument looks sound to me, I still lack experience with abstract algebra and would appreciate it if anyone could verify the proof, or in the

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is to prove that "$\phi(x)\neq \psi(x)$ implies that $G$ and $G'$ are not isomorphic", so you should explain this more.

It would go as follows: for all $n\in\mathbb N$, $\phi(a^n) = \phi(a)^n = \psi(a)^n = \psi(a^n)$, so $\phi$ and $\psi$ coincide on $\langle a \rangle$. Since $\langle a\rangle = G$, the result follows. Note that you don't need $\phi$ to be an isomorphism, it is true that whenever $\phi$ is a group homomorphism whose domain is a cyclic group, $\phi$ is determined by its value on a generator of the domain.